# Full image is not displayed through servlet . It is not complete at bottom

Tags: java, servlets

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    logger.info("Inside Upload Image Preview---");

    String imageName = request.getParameter("imgName");
    String contentType = "image/";

    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    logger.info("Inside Upload Image Preview---Before try block.");

    try {
        String imageExt = imageName.substring(imageName.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
        logger.info("conent Type for the response is "+contentType);
        logger.info("Image name  is "+imageName);

        contentType = contentType + imageExt;
        response.setContentType(contentType);

        String dirPath= System.getProperty(AMPortletConstants.JBOSS_HOME_DIR)+"/image/";
        File fileName = new File(dirPath+imageName);

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        input = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        logger.info("Image added in response.");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.error("Exception in UploadImagePreview======="+exception);
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>imagePreview</servlet-name>
<servlet-lass>com.xxxxxx.portlet.UploadImagePreview</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imagePreview</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxxxxxImages/*</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

Url Pattern we hit

> /xxxxxxxx-portlet/xxxxxxImages/img?imgName=Test.png

It displays the image in browser but problem is that image is not complete . Minor bottom part is missing. Kindly provide the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing

```
finally
{
    output.flush();
    output.close();
}
```

Actually `close()` calls `flush()` but the important part regarding your question is the missing flush of the stream. Always remember to `close()` your resources, or you're in for a world of hurt with resource leaks :-)

Cheers,

Comment: hi i have the same issue  Minor bottom part is missing, i close the outputstream and still the bottom part is missing . any idea ? thanks      `getResponse().getOutputStream().flush();` and `getResponse().getOutputStream().close();`  ... my `byte[] buf = new byte[1024];` is it related ?

Comment: @Secondo hard to say without seeing your code in entirety - how is `buf` used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738815/missing-bottom-part-of-image-using-getresponse-getoutputstream-write

Comment: hi i tried what you suggested but i still got an image with missing bottom part.